# What's a polyadic function?

Tags: arguments

There's no clear definition for a polyadic function on the internet. Please help me with a clear definition. On the other hand, there is some information about  variadic functions available. Variadic functions mean that they take a variable number of arguments and apparently, such functions are supported by C.

Answer (score 2):

Adic stands for number of arguments. So poly + adic means multiple number of arguments that a function can take. It will have more than 1 argument. In python you can define the arguments where you declare it. Hope that helps.

Arithmetic functions in LISP language are polyadic. ie, they can take multiple arguments.

Comment: So we can assume that the number of args are fixed in this case?

Comment: Brother, just now I said it can take multiple arguments. That is the main thing. That is the reason why we use polyadic functions.

Comment: I got what you said. What I'm asking is if the number of arguments, though multiple, are fixed or not? For e.g. a polyadic function can take four arguments. Can it also take 5 arguments? Can vary the number of parameters like variadic functions?

Comment: It can take n number of arguments. 5 or 6 or 60.